Invalid Hook call with esm.sh, react-three-fiber in Browser
I have this simple code in html to run a react-three-fiber canvas -


    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <script type="importmap">
            {
              "imports": {
                "@jsxImportSource": "https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0?dev",
                "react-dom/client": "https://esm.sh/react-dom@18.2.0/client?dev",
                "@react-three/fiber": "https://esm.sh/@react-three/fiber?dev"
              }
            }
        </script>
        <script type="module" src="https://esm.sh/run"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
    
    <script type="text/babel" >
        import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
        import {Canvas} from '@react-three/fiber';
    
        function App() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Canvas >
                    </Canvas>
                </div>
            );
        }
    
        createRoot(window.root).render(<App />);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>



But I get the error -
its-fine.development.mjs:68 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.


react.development.js:1650 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
    at Module.useMemo2 (react.development.js:1650:21)
    at Canvas (react-three-fiber.esm.js:125:9)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:19226:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21636:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26560:12)


its-fine.development.mjs:68 The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(Canvas)> component:

    at Canvas (https://esm.sh/v135/@react-three/fiber@8.16.6/es2022/fiber.development.mjs:2015:3)
    at FiberProvider (https://esm.sh/v135/its-fine@1.2.5/es2022/its-fine.development.mjs:71:21)
    at CanvasWrapper
    at div
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

In the sources tab, I do see react v18.2.0 and v18.3.1, I am not sure why there are 2 versions of react there but maybe that is reason for the invalid hooks error.
How can I resolve this issue?
CodeSandBox

Downgrading react-three-fiber to v8.15.19 works without issues.
